# JWT Auth for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to authenticate a user from App, and I have written the API in laravel. I want to know what is the difference between JWTAuth::fromUser($user),JWTAuth::toUser($user) and JWTAuth::attempt($user) and any advantages over using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> JWTAuth::fromUser($user)

If you have user instance already and want to generate token for that user then you use `fromUser`

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

> JWTAuth::attempt($user)

This function is used to authenticate user from credentials and if authenticate success then it generate token for authenticated user

```
if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
}
```

> JWTAuth::toUser($user)

When you want to get user from `token` then you use `toUser` method. like this

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
```

For details you can check it here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens

Comment: So, for just login purpose i could use either of fromUser or toUser , based on what i possess, the user object or just the credentials right?

Comment: for login purpose, if you have `$credentials` then use `attempt`, but if you have `user` instance already then use `fromUser`. When you call api with `token` then you will use `toUser` to get user from token.

Comment: Basically, i already have the user instance validated. Now i need token. So i guess fromUser suits my need. Ok thank you very much